# How to use Scala 2.10 implicit classes

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-2.10

I thought this would be correct usage of the new implicit classes of Scala 2.10:

```
implicit case class IntOps(i: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def twice = i * 2
}

11.twice
```

Apparently not:

```
<console>:13: error: value twice is not a member of Int
              11.twice
                 ^
```

Am I missing something (Scala 2.10.0-M6)?

Comment: This is a bug. I opened [SI-6227](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6227), though it would not surprise me to discover it's a duplicate.

Comment: an `implicit class` cannot be a `case class`, that's the only reason.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A clue is the desugaring of implicit classes, explained in [the SIP-13](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/implicit-classes.html):

```
implicit class RichInt(n: Int) extends Ordered[Int] {
def min(m: Int): Int = if (n <= m) n else m
...
}
```

will be transformed by the compiler as follows:

```
class RichInt(n: Int) extends Ordered[Int] {
def min(m: Int): Int = if (n <= m) n else m
...
}
implicit final def RichInt(n: Int): RichInt = new RichInt(n)
```

As you can see, the implicit function that is created has the same name as the original classes. I guess it's done like this to make implicit classes easier to import.

Thus in your case, when you create an implicit **case** class, there is a conflict between the method name created by the `implicit` keyword and the companion object created by the `case` keyword.

Comment: To me, this looks more like a bug. `case` creates an `apply` method, implicit a method with the name of the class.

Comment: @Nicolas sorry for asking after 3+ years. But I would appreciate if you can show how to obtain the desugared code. Thanks

Comment: @Polymerase In that cas, I took the definition from the SIP. You can however, use `scalac -Xprint:parse <filename.scala>` to see how the code is desugared. You can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9892350/1730) and its comment.

Answer (score 2):

This shows there is an ambiguity:

```
val ops: IntOps = 11

<console>:11: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method IntOps of type (i: Int)IntOps
and  object IntOps of type IntOps.type
match argument types (Int) and expected result type IntOps
       val ops: IntOps = 11
                         ^
```

Not sure what exactly happens. But when not using a `case class` it seems fine:

```
implicit class IntOps(val i: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def twice = i * 2
}

11.twice  // ok
```