# scala: Create a Sequence of tuples with a constant key

Tags: scala

Given a constant value and a potentially long Sequence:

```
   a:String = "A"
   bs = List(1, 2, 3)
```

How can you most efficiently construct a Sequence of tuples with the first element equalling a?

```
Seq(
    ( "A", 1 ),
    ( "A", 2 ),
    ( "A", 3 )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use a map:

```
val list = List(1,2,3)

list.map(("A",_))
```

**Output:**

```
res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((A,1), (A,2), (A,3))
```

Comment: A quick note, if this collection is going to be transformed again, consider using `iterator`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I disagree. For anything that doesn't require performance optimization (hundreds of thousands of elements, transformed continously) one should always go for the immutable approach - for the sole reason of code quality.

Comment: The question is ideally asking for the most efficient approach.

Comment: @Jethro I don't think there is a difference in efficiency wether a `List` or an `Iterator` is constructed. Only when it comes to transformation there might be.

Comment: @MarkusAppel While I agree with you _(I would never expose an Iterator)_, the question asked about performance. I clearly stated that only if the collection is going to be transformed latter. - Now, I must agree I was very vague, let me rephrase myself: If you are going to perform **MULTIPLE & IMMEDIATE** transformations to the same collection, consider using `iterator` first and at the end, call one of the `to` methods to receive back an immutable collection with all changes applied at once. As a best practice, consider keeping all that in the scope of a method, private to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `map` just like in the answer provided by @Pedro or you can use `for` and `yield` as below:

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
 val tuple = for {
    i <- list
  } yield ("A",i)
  println(tuple)
```

**Output:**

```
List((A,1), (A,2), (A,3))
```

You are also asking about the efficient way in your question. Different developers have different opinions between the efficiency of `for` and `map`. So, I guess going through the links below gives you more knowledge about the efficiency part.

[for vs map in functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417100/for-vs-map-in-functional-programming)

[Scala style: for vs foreach, filter, map and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877351/scala-style-for-vs-foreach-filter-map-and-others)

[Getting the desugared part of a Scala for/comprehension expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891407/getting-the-desugared-part-of-a-scala-for-comprehension-expression)

Answer (score 1):

Since the most efficient would be to pass (to further receiver) just the seq, and  the receiver tuple the elements there, I'd do it with views.

```
val first = "A"
val bs = (1 to 1000000).view
further( bs.map((first, _)) )
```