# SBT Scala project de-sugared

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

If I have an small/medium size SBT Scala (with Akka) project and would like to see the de-sugared output from scalac, how would I do this?

I've found a couple of [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891407/getting-the-desugared-part-of-a-scala-for-comprehension-expression) for displaying small functions or class files but the examples aren't using external classes (ie. imports).  I'd like to see what one function in my ScalaTest is de-sugaring to but there are so many dependencies that a simple `scala -print myFile.scala` doesn't work.

Thoughts on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

With SBT 0.13, you can export the command line to run the scala compiler from the command line with all the right dependencies on the classpath:

```
> compile
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/jason/code/scratch3/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Oct 31, 2013 7:28:50 PM
> export compile
scalac -bootclasspath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Classes/jsfd.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Frameworks/JavaRuntimeSupport.framework/Resources/Java/JavaRuntimeSupport.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Classes/ui.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Classes/laf.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Classes/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Classes/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Classes/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Classes/charsets.jar:/Users/jason/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.10.3.jar -classpath /Users/jason/code/scratch3/target/scala-2.10/classes:/Users/jason/.ivy2/cache/org.scalacheck/scalacheck_2.10/jars/scalacheck_2.10-1.10.1.jar:/Users/jason/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-tools.testing/test-interface/jars/test-interface-0.5.jar:/Users/jason/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-actors/jars/scala-actors-2.10.1.jar /Users/jason/code/scratch3/src/main/scala/Exercise.scala /Users/jason/code/scratch3/src/main/scala/Test.scala
```

You can take that, prune it down the file that you're interested in, and add `-print` or similar.

I once automated this so you could do this from within SBT with a new command, `compile-quick`:

https://github.com/retronym/scratch/blob/master/20111022/project/CompileQuickPlugin.scala
https://github.com/retronym/scratch/blob/master/20111022/sbt.log

But I haven't checked if this works with the current SBT release.

Answer (score 1):

My hack is to generally compile it and then use jd-gui to decompile it. Messes up sometimes, but helps me understand 99% of the sugar.