# for-expression to flatMap Conversion

Tags: scala

The following `for-expression` seems intuitive to me. Take each item in `List(1)`, then map over `List("a")`, and then return a `List[(Int, String)]`.

```
scala> val x = for {
     | a <- List(1)
     | b <- List("a")
     | } yield (a,b)
x: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,a))
```

Now, converting it to a `flatMap`, it seems less clear to me. If I understand correctly, I need to call `flatMap` first since I'm taking the initial `List(1)`, and then applying a function to convert from `A => List[B]`.

```
scala> List(1).flatMap(a => List("a").map(b => (a,b) ))
res0: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,a))
```

After using the flatMap, it seemed necessary to use a `map` since I needed to go from `A => B`.

But, as the number of items increases in the `for-expression` (say 2 to 3 items), how do I know whether to use a `map` or `flatMap` when converting from `for-expression` to `flatMap`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the desugared part of a Scala for/comprehension expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891407/getting-the-desugared-part-of-a-scala-for-comprehension-expression)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In using the for comprehension you always `flatMap` until the last value that you extract which you `map`. So if you have three items:

```
  for {
    a <- List("a")
    b <- List("b")
    c <- List("c")
  } yield (a, b, c)
```

It would be the same as:

```
  List("a").flatMap(a => List("b").flatMap(b => List("c").map(c => (a, b, c))))
```

If you look at the signature of `flatMap` it's `A => M[B]`. So as we add elements to the for comprehension we need to `flatMap` them in since we continue to add `M[B]` to the comprehension. When we get to the last element, there's nothing left to add so we use `map` since we just want to go from `A => B`. Hope that makes sense, if not take you should watch some of the videos in the Reactive Programming class on Coursera as they go over this quite a bit.

Comment: See also [Daniel Sobral's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/what-is-scalas-yield/1059501#1059501), which is also found  in the Odersky book, and less readably, in the spec.