# What do these symbols signify in scala?

Tags: scala, symbols

I am new in scala and was working with a few basic concepts. There are quite a few symbols used in scala, and few of them are still not very clear to me. I found this useful [guide](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/pdfs/Scala%20Quick%20Reference.pdf) that has a summary of the various scala symbols. 
I don't clearly get the meaning of the following symbol (<-):

```
for (arg <- args)
```

A few documents that I found say "Used in for comprehensions in generator expressions". But I don't really understand what it means. Could somebody help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: answered by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891407/getting-the-desugared-part-of-a-scala-for-comprehension-expression

Comment: Try to read as `element of`. 
So: `for (arg elment of args) { doSomething}`

Comment: @NabilA. that's very limited to containers. It has a much broader semantic that applies to anything with a `flatMap`

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I know. But this works fine for scala standard classes as `Collections`, `Option`, `Try` and `Future`. This was a comment to help a beginner not a paragraph in a book.