# How does TraversableLike.exists invoke my custom collections foreach

Tags: scala

This code returns true as expected:

```
class MyList extends Traversable[Int] {
  def foreach[U](f: Int => U) = {
    f(1)
    f(2)
    f(3)
  }
}
object Test extends App {
  println(new MyList().exists(_ == 2))
}
```

`MyList` only needs to define `foreach` in order to implement a `Traversable`. So, somewhere the `exists` function calls `MyList.foreach`. Setting a breakpoint at `f(1)`, I see that `foreach` is called by `TraversableLike` line 352 `for (x <- this)`. So, is `x <- this` calling foreach? How? I don't see the call to `foreach` anywhere.

```
  349: def exists(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
  350:   var result = false
  351:   breakable {
  352:     for (x <- this)
  353:       if (p(x)) { result = true; break }
  354:   }
  355:   result
  366: }
```

Comment: It's `for` that calls `foreach`, I think.

Comment: Yes, all `for` comprehensions are rewritten to `map`, `flatMap`, and `foreach` (whichever is needed) by the compiler.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891407/getting-the-desugared-part-of-a-scala-for-comprehension-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scala specification regarding [For Comprehension and For Loops](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops) talks about this exactly:

> The precise meaning of generators and guards is defined by translation
>   to invocations of four methods: `map`, `withFilter`, `flatMap`, and `foreach`.
>   These methods can be implemented in different ways for different
>   carrier types.

So the translation is effectively:

```
def exists(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
  var result = false
  breakable {
    this.foreach(x => if (p(x)) { result = true; break })
  }
  result
}
```

And that is why you're see your `foreach` being invoked.

For different for comprehensions you may see different translations, which are all specified in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

Yuval is correct. But in general, I find referring to the link he gives becomes a bit tiresome. Especially when I am deep inside a `for` loop I don't understand.

I've developed a macro that helps me figure out how things get de-sugared. It's pretty handy and works from the `scala` REPL. Just open up a session, and paste in

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

// inspect how scala has desugared your code
def traceSugar[T](t: T): T = macro impl
def impl(c: Context)(t: c.Tree): c.Tree = { println(t); t }
```

Then, if you ever want to see how something de-sugars, just wrap it in `traceSugar`. It will print the de-sugared version and evaluate the expression. Very handy for the hairier `for` loops. In your case,

```
scala> traceSugar {
 |   var result = false
 |   breakable {
 |     for (x <- Seq(1,2,3))
 |       if (x > 1) { result = true; break }
 |   }
 |   result
 | }
```

Results in

```
{
  var result: Boolean = false;
  scala.util.control.Breaks.breakable(collection.this.Seq.apply[Int](1, 2, 3).foreach[Unit](((x: Int) => if (x.>(1))
    {
      result = true;
      scala.util.control.Breaks.break()
    }
  else
    ())));
  result
}
res8: Boolean = true
```

You see the `foreach`, as well as how `breakable` works.