# Combine call-by-name colon operator and space incoherency

Tags: scala

Here is the following problem. When I run the following:

```
object  Test {
  def /:(s: => Unit) = {
    println("/:")
    s
  }
}

println("A") /: Test
```

It prints:

```
A
/:
```

However, I was expecting it to print:

```
/:
A
```

since the last expression was supposedly rewritten `Test./:(println("A"))` - which by the way, gives the second value.

Does anybody know a way to make the first syntax work, e.g. `println("A") /: Test` but with call-by-name ?

**Edit**

Using the [desugar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19774408/1287856) method, I found out that the calls are desugared differently.

```
> desugar { println("A") /: Test}
 val x$1: Unit = println("A");
 Test./:(x$1)
```

Hence I am still wondering why this choice.

Comment: Why do you "suppose" that the expression is equivalent to `Test./:(println("A"))`? The specification says: "A left-associative binary operation `e1 op e2` is interpreted as `e1.op(e2)`. If `op` is right-associative, the same operation is interpreted as `{ val x = e1; e2.op(x) }`, where `x` is a fresh name." So, it is equivalent to `{ val x = println("A"); Test./:(x) }`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a [known issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1980).
If you compile with -Xlint option you should see a [warning](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2852).

```
$ scalac -Xlint temp.scala
temp.scala:2: warning: by-name parameters will be evaluated eagerly when called 
              as a right-associative infix operator. For more details, see SI-1980.
    def /:(s: => Unit) = {
        ^
one warning found
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I think is the fact that you expect a by name parameter of type `Unit` - there is only one unit, hence the name: `()`.

I found the following works:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object  Test {
  def /:(s: () => Unit) = {
    println("/:")
    s()
  }
}

val p = () => println("A")
p /: Test

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

/:
A
defined object Test
p: () => Unit = <function0>
res5: Any = ()
```

Comment: I bet this work, but the problem is not because of the Unit. I want to be able to write to the end of the line `:/ Test` and have something be printed before. I don't want to rewrite the argument itself.