# Swapping statements in for-comprehension in Scala shows strange behavior

Tags: scala

I swapped the order to two seemingly independent lines in a for-comprehension. The first gives expected result, while second throws exception. Why is this happening?

```
scala> for (a <- 1 to 3; b <- Some(2)) yield (a, b);
res6: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = Vector((1,2), 
(2,2), (3,2))

scala> for (b <- Some(2); a <- 1 to 3) yield (a, b);
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)]
required: Option[?]
      for (b <- Some(2); a <- 1 to 3) yield (a, b);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't *throw exception*, this is *compile error*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your [compiled code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9892350/432903), you see that `for yield` is desugered to `flatMap` equivalent to `(1 to 3).flatMap(a => Some(2).map(b => (a, b)))` which is valid.

```
scalac -Xprint:parser Test.scala
[[syntax trees at end of                    parser]] // Test.scala
package <empty> {
  object T extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val x = 1.to(3).flatMap(((a) => Some(2).map(((b) => scala.Tuple2(a, b)))));
      println(x)
    }
  }
}
```

So, the inner computation is `Some[Tuple2]` wrapped in a outer `List`/ `Vector` context that's why you are able to `flatMap` to outer context as `flatMap` def is

```
final override def flatMap[B](f: Option[Int] => scala.collection.IterableOnce[B]): List[B]
```

**While in second example,**

```
Some(2).flatMap(b => List(1, 2, 3).map(a => (a, b)))
```

your are asking to `.flatMap` on `Some` context while the inner context being `List`/ or `Vector`. So it can not `flatMap`.

In summary what should work for `flatMap` is,

```
| Outer context | Inner context | Result    | example                  
|
|---------------|---------------|-----------|----------------------------------------
| List          | List[a]       | List[a]   | List(List(1, 2), List(2)).flatMap(a => a)
| List          | Option[a]     | List[a]   | List(Some(1), Some(2)).flatMap(a => a)
| Option        | Option[a]     | Option[a] | Some(1).flatMap(a => Some(a))
```

Comment: yes You are right. Flatmap on option takes a function that returns an option.